# Assembly tower of Hanoi segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, arm

```
.data
.set BUFFERSIZE,20

num: .word 0
frompeg: .word 0
topeg: .word 0
auxpeg: .word 0

buffer:
    .space BUFFERSIZE,0
usagemsg:
    .asciz "Enter the number of disks : "

splash:
    .asciz "The moves to solve the Tower of Hanoi are:\n"

lessmsg:
    .asciz "Tower of Hanoi makes no sense with %d disks\n"

finalprint:
    .asciz "Move disk 1 from peg %d to peg %d\n"

midprint:
    .asciz "Move disk %d from peg %d to peg %d\n"
.text
.global main
.global towers

main:
    stmfd sp!,{r4-r8,lr}   @ Save lr on the stack

    ldr r0,=usagemsg
    bl printf

    ldr r0,=buffer      @ Argument 1: buffer address
    ldr r1,=BUFFERSIZE  @ Argument 2: size of the buffer
    ldr r2,=stdin       @ Address of stdin variable in memory
    ldr r2,[r2]         @ Argument 3: value of stdin
    bl fgets

    ldr r0,=buffer
    bl atoi

    mov r1, r0

    cmp r1, #1
    blt less1

    ldr r0,=splash
    bl printf   

    mov r0, r1
    mov r1, #1
    mov r2, #2
    mov r3, #3
    bl towers

    stmfd sp!,{r4-r8,lr}  @ Restore lr from the stack
    bx lr

towers:
    stmfd sp!,{r0-r8,lr}
    @ Checks if num == 1
    cmp r0, #1
    beq done2

    sub r0, r0, #-1
    mov r4, r2
    mov r2, r3 @ 2 has auxpeg
    mov r3, r4 @ 3 has topeg
    bl towers
    add r0, r0, #1


    mov r5, r0 @ 5 has num
    mov r6, r1 @ 6 has frompeg
    mov r7, r2 @ 7 has auxpeg
    mov r8, r3 @ 8 has topeg
    mov r1, r5
    mov r2, r6
    mov r3, r8
    ldr r0,=midprint
    bl printf

    mov r0, r5
    mov r1, r7
    mov r2, r8
    mov r3, r6
    sub r0, r0, #-1
    bl towers
    ldmfd sp!,{r0-r8,lr}  @ Restore lr from the stack
    bx lr 


done2:

    ldr r0,=finalprint
    bl printf

    ldmfd sp!,{r0-r8,lr}  @ Restore lr from the stack
    bx lr  


less1:
    ldr r0,=lessmsg
    bl printf 
    ldmfd sp!,{r4-r8,lr}  @ Restore lr from the stack
    bx lr
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of disks : 3
The moves to solve the Tower of Hanoi are:
Move disk 1 from peg 1 to peg 3
Move disk 2 from peg 1 to peg 2
Segmentation Fault
```

I think I have an issue with registers during recursion. I assumed that when a "bl towers" is called, it creates 8 new registers for that new function to use but perhaps that is not the case.  But I am not sure how to fix this

I wrote what I am trying to create in c

```
void towers(int num, int frompeg, int topeg, int auxpeg){
    if (num == 1)
    {
        printf("Move disk 1 from peg %d to peg %d\n", frompeg, topeg);
        return;
    }
    towers(num - 1, frompeg, auxpeg, topeg);
    printf("Move disk %d from peg %d to peg %d\n", num, frompeg, topeg);
    towers(num - 1, auxpeg, topeg, frompeg);
}
```

Comment: `ldmfd sp!,{lr}` <-- that doesn't match the `stmfd` in `main`.

Comment: @Michael fixed it but still got the same seg fault

Comment: Run it in a debugger?

Comment: CPU can't create new registers (where? it's memory directly in the CPU, only few bytes available), the registers are absolute globals. Recursive functions can store register values into RAM memory at the start and restore before return (things like `stmfd / ldmfd` can be used for that, for example).